# Docker - NPM rename error for Ganache CLI

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, ganache

I am trying to replicate this project:
[GitHub project on Ethereum](https://github.com/just4give/p2p-carsell-ethereum-raspi)

As instructed I ran `docker-compose up`
However I am continuously running into this error. I tried using `npm verify cache` and other methods but all in vain

[When docker-compose up is ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwNA1.png)

[Actual Error in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc5Mq.png)

Finally I removed the global flag to -D in the Docker Test File
`

```
FROM node:6.9
RUN npm install -D ganache-cli
EXPOSE 8545
ENTRYPOINT [ "ganache-cli" ]
```

This worked well for the previous error but I ran into a new error

[The latest error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kWBi.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Node.js version 6.9? For real?

Comment: First of all, you're posting your errors as images. This is not searchable and not understandable for those who use screen readers.